# Is it possible to create an email address using SMTP and PHP on server?

Tags: php, smtp

Is it possible to create an email address using SMTP and PHP on server programmatically with PHP or maybe some other programming language?
I have an hosting account with a Bluehost.  The host lets us create email address manually. Example: something@mydomain.com
Then people can send emails to the account because when the account is created, it also has
its own inbox. I wanted to know if it is possible to make those email accounts somehow in PHP. Im using Bluehost as my domain host.

Comment: What do you mean by "create"? Do you mean send email for ("from") an arbitrary email address?

Comment: please elaborate... what do you mean by "create an email address" ? an account/a mailbox ? if so then this has AFAIk nothing to do with SMTP... it depends solely on the mailserver and its API and your permissions (you most likely need admin privileges)... so which mailserver ? what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: -1 for laziness. This question is basically impossible to answer in its current form, because it makes no sense. I can't even think of a "nearby" question that *does* make sense (although Yahia has made a respectable effort), otherwise I would either propose it in a comment (as Yahia has done) or edit your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, SMTP is a mail **transfer** protocol, it is not applicable for managing a mail server. On the other hand a specific mail server may have an interface which can be used to create users accounts. For example Apache James contains a Telnet like interface and among others it has a command for creating a new user account. This can be considered easily scriptable, but I do not know how much help PHP provides in this specific case.